# How to return after execution of a callback in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, callback

```
    function myFunction(){
    let somevariable=1;
    doSomething({},(data)=>{
        somevariable=data;
    });
    return somevariable;
}
```

The return should happen only after the callback which is inside doSomething , how will i do it

Comment: Is doSomething function an async function?

Comment: @AndreySmolko No

Comment: Depends on what doSomething does with the function you pass it.  It may ignore that parameter completely.